# Remove Black LEFT and TOP on <INPUT>

Tags: html, css, input, styles, textarea

I am trying to make an `<input>` text field with the color code `#7d5993`, but I see that the top and left are black and the bottom and right are my color. Is there any way to make the entire border my color like how the `<textarea>` would look?

[Here's my code](http://jsfiddle.net/7kE7R/13/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add property border-style override default border style of the textarea and input

```
border-style:solid;
```

You can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqDjx/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to define `border-style:solid` also like this:

```
input{border:2px solid red;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7kE7R/15/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    input{border: 1px solid #7d5993; border-width:2px;}
    input:focus{border: 1px  solid #5190dd; border-width:2px;outline:none;}

    textarea{border: 1px solid #7d5993;border-width:2px;}
    textarea:focus{border: 1px solid #5190dd; border-width:2px; outline:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
border-style:solid
```

check out my solution here
http://jsfiddle.net/fvN8T/

Comment: and i thought i as the first :|